# Solidity Clones Contracts: How to save deployer as a storage variable which can be called in created clones?

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, transfer, proxy-contracts, clone

I am using the OpenZeppelin Clones Library so that users of my dapp can create clones of my implementation contract. My dapp will be following the EIP-1167 standard.

For functionality, I will need to save the deployer address (of implementation contract). The way one would traditionally do this would be in the constructor, however clone contracts do not read the 'creation-code' and they only view 'runtime-code', so if I save deployer address using a constructor, the cloned contracts will not be able to access that saved variable (as far as I know).

The reason I want to save the deployer address is because I would like to be paid out a certain percentage of the balance of all the cloned contracts.

Can someone please tell me how I would go about saving the deployer address so that I can be paid out from the cloned contracts. I am also open to other means of going about this, so long as I am able to receive payments to my deployer address.

One idea I have is to store my deployer address (or any other personal address) as a variable in the implementation contract and divert all payments to that address. This would remove the need of having to set a deployer address in the constructor.

Would this be a good way to go about it or is there a more 'correct' method which I can use for this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The most used method is having a `initialize` function in the implementation, where you can store "once and for all" your factory variable.

So for example, this is how the implementation may look:

```
contract Implementation {
    bool private initialized;

    address public deployer;   // aka the factory
    address public user;

    function initialize(address _user) public {
        require(!initialized, "Already initialized!");
        initialized = true;

        deployer = msg.sender;
        user = _user;
    }

    ...
}
```

The `initialize` function must be called by the deployer (Factory) immediately after deploying the contract. Example:

```
interface IImplementation {
    function initialize(address) external;
}

contract Factory {
    address public implementation = 0x...;

    // an user calls this function to make a new contract (clone)
    function createNewContract() public {
        address newcontract = Clones.clone(implementation);
        IImplementation(newcontract).initialize(msg.sender);
    }

    ...
}
```